# Powershell - Run command from a path with spaces

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute a process from a path that is stored in a variable (the value of the variable is the result of the Get-Location command).
This works only when the directory doesn't have spaces.
I found many ways to scape the spaces but those only work when you assign the path manually.
Is there any other way?

This is the code:

```
$userCred = Get-Credential "Domain\$admAccount"
$currentDir = Get-Location
Start-Process "pwd_user.exe" -WorkingDirectory $currentDir -Credential $userCred
```

I tried:

```
"$currentDir"
$currentDir -replace ' ', '` '
&$currentDir
"&$currentDir"
```

None of these work.

Comment: What do you mean by "none of these work"? How does it fail? Works fine on my system, though your use of `Get-Location` is probably not necessary. You could try `Start-Process "pwd_user.exe" -WorkingDirectory . -Credential $userCred` - use `.` to refer to the directory you're in.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for WorkingDirectory is the current directory. I don't see why you need this variable in the first place. As for the variable, I guess you could give expanding the Path-property a shot.

```
Start-Process "pwd_user.exe" -WorkingDirectory $currentDir.Path -Credential $userCred
```

For the unsuccesful replace you will need to expand the property;

```
$currentDir.Path -replace ' ', '` '
```